# OpenX has been installed, but no configuration file was found

Tags: openx

I installed OpenX in my server, I've created a campaign and banner for that campaign and linked that campaign to a zone.
I took a javascript invocation code, but the banner is not coming.
Then i took iframe tage, and now i am getting this error

> OpenX has been installed, but no configuration file was found

Please help me in this

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to go to the configuration area using the Administrator account?

Do you have a file under the dir /var on your openx installation with .conf.php extension?

Answer (score 0):

If your invocation code uses a different domain to the one used when installing your openx server, then might need to add a default.conf.php file to your openx var directory to point to the realConf file created during setup.

http://www.openx.com/support/faqs/technical#settings

Answer (score 0):

Change the Permission  :

```
$chmod -R 777 openx/var
```

Regards,

Chinnu.G